# Correctly point DNS to subdomain from cloudflare to cpanel server?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cloudflare, cpanel

I have a CPANEL server hosting some websites and webmails, a couple of days ago I was asked to add SSL security to this websites and decided to use cloud flare to do this. So I added the domain in cloud flare and automatically imported the DNS records that CF detected.

So the home page and emails are working like a charm, the problem is with a landing page accesible from a subdomain:

corporativo.conceptlounge.mx

If I try to access this page using **www.** it just doesn't loads. And some people can't load it from certain places (different networks).

My DNS records on CPANEL are:

[image]

And 19 more records but those are related to mail, cpanel, auto discover, etc.

And this is how Im trying to use them in cloud flare, I had to manually add subdomain records cause they didn't add automatically:

[image]

Comment: As of 042920 Cloudflare's standard (unpaid) SSL does not support more than one subdomain. `www.corporativo.conceptlounge.mx` is two subdomains. See [community.cloudflare.com](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-ssl-not-working-on-subdomains/3792)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 042920 Cloudflare's standard (unpaid) SSL does not support more than one subdomain. `www.corporativo.conceptlounge.mx` is two subdomains. See [community.cloudflare.com:](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-ssl-not-working-on-subdomains/3792)

```
"Our standard SSL does not support more than one subdomain ..."
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, didn't know